# ServiceLoader double iterator issues

Tags: java

Is this a known issue? I had trouble finding any search results.

When iterating over a ServiceLoader while an iteration already is in progress, the first iteration will be aborted. For example, assuming there are at least two implementations of `Foo`, the following code will fail with an AssertionError:

```
ServiceLoader<Foo> loader = ServiceLoader.load(Foo.class);
Iterator<Foo> iter1 = loader.iterator();
iter1.next();

Iterator<Foo> iter2 = loader.iterator();
while (iter2.hasNext()) {
    iter2.next();
}

assert iter1.hasNext();
```

This only seems to occur, if the second iterator really terminates. The code will succeed in this variation for example:

```
ServiceLoader<Foo> loader = ServiceLoader.load(Foo.class);
Iterator<Foo> iter1 = loader.iterator();
iter1.next();

Iterator<Foo> iter2 = loader.iterator();
iter2.next();

assert iter1.hasNext();
```

Is this a bug or a feature? :p

Is there a ticket for this already anywhere?

Comment: Have you tried searching the bug database?

Comment: So the normal course of action when finding a bug without a bug report would be to submit a bug report.

Comment: @Tom Thanks for the response. I'm glad it wasn't just me missing something obvious. I have filed a bug and will post a link here as soon as it gets published.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a bug. I think it is since iterator.next() invokes next() on same reference of a lazy iterator internally.
This behavior violates "Principle of least astonishment"

Comment: @ring: that's a very possible reason, but how is that not a bug? Nothing in the documentation suggests that you may only call `iterator()` once or that multiple `Iterators` depend on each other in some way.

Comment: This could be a bug, edited my response. I was rather thinking why would one want to have multiple iterators on the ServiceLoader.
This violates "Principle of least astonishment " comparing to `Iterators` elsewhere in Java

Comment: Almost a year later, Sun^H^H^H Oracle has still not reviewed the bug I filed. I've marked your answer as the accepted answer.